# Unable to mvn release:perform

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm creating pipeline for new artifact and want to test it locally, before creating Jenkins job on real environment.

The configuration is next: local directory as git repo and Nexus running in docker.

I was able to perform `mvn release:prepare  -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdevelopmentVersion=1.15.0 -DpushChanges=true -DreleaseVersion=1.14.0 -Dtag=v1.14.0`

It went fine, updated versions in my poms. That's ok.

I was able to `mvn deploy` SNAPSHOT to my Nexus. Ok.

I'm unable to make `mvn release:perform`, it fails with different errors each time. Now I'm stuck with this: `Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository releases (${url}) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory`

My configs are:

`pom.xml`

```
 <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:/Users/fau/Documents/work/localgit/reponame/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:/Users/fau/Documents/work/localgit/reponame/</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
  <id>releases</id>
  <url>http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
 </repository>
 <snapshotRepository>
  <id>snapshots</id>
  <url>http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

In build section I also have:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
               <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
               <releaseProfiles>myprofile</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My settings.xml:

```
<settings>
 <servers>
        <server>
                <id>releases</id>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin123</password>
        </server>            
        <server>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin123</password>
        </server>            
</servers>

<profiles>
<profile>
        <id>myprofile</id>
        <properties>            
             <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
             <repositoryUrl>    http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</repositoryUrl>
            <snapshotsRepositoryId>snapshots</snapshotsRepositoryId>
            <snapshotsUrl>http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</snapshotsUrl>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>releases</id>                      <url>http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>                    
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <url>http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>                    
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
   <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

I'm using:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T17:51:42+04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.2/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: why do you run deploy between mvn:prepare and mvn:perform? if the 'prepare' is successful, the 'perform' will deploy the release to the repo. BTW why your 'nextDevVersion' is not a 'snapshot' (1.15.0)?

Comment: The order for doing releases is simply: `mvn release:prepare` and aferwards `mvn release:perform` nothing else is needed. Everything else deploy etc. is handled automatically. BTW. I would suggest to use the most up-to-date plugin version (2.5.1) of maven-release-plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven-release-plugin deploy goal fails on project with folder at top level in git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632947/maven-release-plugin-deploy-goal-fails-on-project-with-folder-at-top-level-in-gi)